# Updating Firebase Database Data with android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using this method to store data in my firebase database:

First i store all the data in a Model Class, called SubjectDataModel,
then i get the push key from the firebase database.

and then i set value to that particular key.

Here is my code :

**SubjectDataModel:**

```
public class SubjectDataModel {

    public String id;
    public String dbName;
    public String subName;
    public String tagline;
    public int preference;

    public SubjectDataModel()
    {

    }

    public SubjectDataModel(String id, String dbName, String subName, String tagline, int preference) {
        this.id = id;
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.subName = subName;
        this.tagline = tagline;
        this.preference = preference;
    }
}
```

**Then i use the following code to push it to the database and then i also store the key id locally.**

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
String id = ref.push().getKey();
SubjectDataModel newSub = new SubjectDataModel(id, txt_dbName, txt_subName, txt_tagline, txt_preference);
ref.child(id).setValue(newSub);
```

Now imagine, later in time, i want to update this data, 
so i have the key id stored, so i can access it, i also have edited all the other data locally, so now if i make a SubjectDataModel Object with that data and again do `ref.child(id).setValue(newSub);` with the stored id, will the data be updated ? Or is there any other method to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i tried this and it works perfectly, like i expected it to. No need for me to use maps or anything. Simplest way to update data.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Data");
SubjectDataModel newSub = new SubjectDataModel(idForUpdate, txt_dbName, txt_subName, txt_tagline, txt_preference);
ref.child(idForUpdate).setValue(newSub);
```

So here basically, i created the object with the required data, and pushed it back to the same id with which i created a node in the firebase database, so it updates that same node with the new values.

Answer (score 1):

updateChildren() is the method you are looking for, refer this documentation [Firebase Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

Here's an example from documentation...

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Comment: What is a map exactly ?

Comment: Thanks though. I found out something else.

Comment: HashMap is used for storing key value pairs.Key is the child and value is the data you want to update under that child.

Comment: so instead of creating a map for a class model, why isnt it better to use the class directly

Comment: its your choice

Comment: no i mean is there any advantages of one over the other ?